# Left and right $R$-module structure on an abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be an abelian group and let $R$ be a ring. Is it true that there exists a bijective correspondence between the left $R$-module structures on $A$ and the right $R$-module structures on $A$?
I think this should be true, based on the fact that a left $R$-module is a right $R^{\operatorname{op}}$-module. But this alone is not enough to prove the statement, it only changes the problem from finding a bijection between left and right $R$-module structures to finding a bijection between right and left $R^{\operatorname{op}}$-module structures. Also, I have found from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009473/find-right-ideals-left-ideals-and-ideals-of-a-ring) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257175/countable-group-uncountably-many-distinct-subgroup) that $\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb{Q}&\mathbb{Q}\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ has a different number of left and right ideals, but this doesn't seem enough to prove that the statement is false.
In conclusion, I'm confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Left $R$-module structures on $A$ are in bijection with ring homomorphisms $R\to End(A)$ and right $R$-module structures on $A$ are in bijection with ring homomorphisms $R^{op}\to End(A)$, or, equivalently, $R\to End(A)^{op}$. Thus it suffices to provide an isomorphism $End(A)\to End(A)^{op}$.

Comment: I believe this fails for something like $A=\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2$, where $End(A)=\begin{pmatrix}\mathbb Z&0\\\mathbb Z/2&\mathbb Z\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you, this seems useful. Could you help me prove how is $\operatorname{End}(A)$ not isomorphic to its opposite ring? I don't understand how the multiplication works here. How can we multiply an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ with an element of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ when we perform matrix multiplication?